# how to make anchor link so it goes to div of external html page

Tags: html

How I can give `anchor link` for a `div` of external file. For example I am in home page, now I want to go to div with id name `"Electronics"` in `products.html` page.

I have tried with doing some thing like

```
  <a href="products.html#Electronics" />
```

But it is not working properly. If some one know alternative way please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you aren't using the XML self-closing tag syntax in your actual example since that the only thing wrong with your code. You need to be more specific and detailed about your problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working properly"? You best bet here is either malformed HTML or a typo in the ID.

Answer (score -2):

Your URL should like this..

```
<a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid">Link</a>
```

in your case it should be

```
<a href="products.html/#Electronics" />
```

I hope it helps you

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZRLB5/

Comment: Why should the URL be an absolute one?

Comment: Re edit: Why must the URL to the document end in a `/`? That will be more likely to produce a 404 than anything else.

Comment: Some servers will allow you to add arbitrary `/`s to the end of URLs and still resolve to the same document. Not all will. There is nothing in the question to suggest that doing so here will help.